# Using the current row in the update statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, row-number, inner-query

What I'm trying to do is the following:
I have a table with multiple authors `SingleAuthor`. This table sometimes contains the same author more than once. What I want to do is update the table and add the author specific number. For instance:

> sat_name -> sat_rowNumber
>   Freddy  -> 1
>   Author2 -> 2
>   Freddy -> 1
>   AnotherOne -> 3

I already have the query that gives me this results:

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY sat_name),

sat_name

FROM SingleAuthor

GROUP BY sat_name`

The problem however is, that I want to insert this data in the `sat_rowNumber` column.
I came this far with the query:

```
UPDATE SingleAuthor SET sat_rowNumber = (   SELECT newTable.numb 
                                            FROM(
                                                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY sat_name) as numb, sat_name 
                                                FROM SingleAuthor  
                                                GROUP BY sat_name) AS newTable 
                                            WHERE newTable.sat_name =) -- the current row in the to be updated table
```

What I want to do is update the `SingleAuthor` table's `sat_rowNumber` to the `newTable.numb` where the current row `sat_name` is equal to the `sat_name` in the `newTable`.

Any insights on how I can reference the to be updated table within the update statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is:

```
where newTable.sat_name = SingleAuthor.sat_name
```

It will reference the outer table, because the one in the subquery is out of scope.  If this were a problem, though, you could give the one in the subquery a different alias.

I think you can write the query more efficiently as:

```
with toupdate as (
    select sa.*, dense_rank() over (order by sat_name) as newVal
    from SingleAuthor sa
)
update toupdate
    set sat_RowNumber = newval
```

The `dense_rank()` function does exactly what you are doing with `row_number()` on the aggregated values.